# Jquery animate() issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't fix this issue,

I have problem when i use

`animate()` in Chrome Browser

```
$( "#slidesAk .ak:visible" ).animate({
    right: "hide",
    opacity: 0.1
}, 500 );
```

for this `right:"hide"`

It works well in Firefox but not in Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/4PQrm/1/

Comment: never seen that "hide" on the right property before o_0 link ?

Comment: [link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (easing function)

Comment: i saw, not easing but 3 special strings cool! i guess you need a selector selecting not:animated  and maybe a .stop(true,false) before anim, looks working in chrome unless you click faster than anim duration

Comment: can you explain in awnser plz ?